# Should I set trainable=True when using embedding?

Tags: tensorflow, cpu-word, embedding

When I using RNN to classify something, should I set `trainable=True` when initialize the embedding ?

I am not sure whether should I set `trainable=True` when initialize the embedding. 
In normal case, without pre-trained embedding file, I should initialize the word-embedding matrix like:

```
bound = -1 # for example
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-bound, maxval=bound)
embedding = tf.get_variable(name=variable_name,
                        shape=[vocab_size, embedding_size],
                        dtype=tf.float32,
                        initializer=initializer)
```

and the parameter `trainable` defaults to `True`.

The original ones looks like :
    some -0.2300489 , -0.7200954 ,  0.5842655 ,  0.7981529 , -0.7432661 ... -0.12576556,  0.3133614 , -0.78932405,  0.38539863,  0.5543554 
and I think it works because all values is in [-1,1].

However, when after been trained by RNN-Classifiy model, the original embedding value will become : 
    some 6.2576456 5.708158 -6.7240534 -7.060843 -6.9045954 ... 0.65268683 6.7722726 5.766225 6.743621 -5.3276224
    one -0.9980886 0.8692293 -0.24473047 0.40041256 -0.8348596 ... -0.9133856 -0.6819365 -0.44985628 -0.43600297 0.51928043
    help -3.8815696 -6.9417324 -7.086827 -2.7665734 3.8522656 ... 2.8540928 6.841772 2.7118142 7.89535 1.4688607

Is it normal or should I normalize it ?

Answer (score 1):

> should I set trainable=True when initialize the embedding ?

Yes, because otherwise the weights are just random values you initialized. By setting trainable True, you are letting the network to learn the embedding by itself.

> Is it normal or should I normalize it ?

Yes it is normal for embedding weight to have the specified value, unless you constrained it. If you want the network to have small weights you can use regularization such as [l2-regularization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/l2_regularizer).